# Java Regular Expression contains search

Tags: java, regex

I am having application in Java where user will give file with filename in specific format. for eg: **james-fcanada-csmith-l.txt**,

Where -f is indicator for firstName, -c is indicator of country and -l is an indicator of lastname.

For this i created this RegEx `([\w\d\s].*)-f([\w\d\s].*)-c([\w\d\s].*)-l`, and it works fine.

But if users changes the order of fields say **smith-ljames-fcanada-c.txt** **(adds lastname first)**, then this RegEx is not working..

Please suggest how to achieve this kind of requirement using RegEx.

Also, Let me know if there are other better ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way for solving your problem might be to have three separate regular expressions, that you run one after another.

For -f use this:

```
^([^-]*-[^f])*([^-]*?)-f([^-]*-[^f])*\..*$
```

http://regexr.com/3bab0

Another, more sophisticated solution might by a parser like `antlr`, which might be too complex for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use regex alternation operator `|`.

```
"([\\w\\d\\s][^-\n]*)-f|([\\w\\d\\s][^-\n]*)-c|([\\w\\d\\s][^-\n]*)-l"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tV6oG0/2)

Comment: This will match either of the three, not the three at the same time and wont detect cases when the name is incorrect (for example if they gave two times their first name, but the last name is missing).

Comment: ya, will update my answer if op clarifies his question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Positive Lookahead` ( I guess that's what it's called).

```
(?=([\w\d\s].*)-f)(?=([\w\d\s].*)-c)(?=([\w\d\s].*)-l)
```

This will match the string in any order.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this with one regular expression. However, if you insist:

```
(\w+)-([fcl])(\w+)-(?!\2)([fcl])(\w+)-(?!\2|\4)([fcl])
```

Explanation:

- Minor remark: I took the liberty to substitute `([\w\d\s].*)` with `(\w+)` which seems to do the job in this case. You can revert it and still get correct results. Btw `\w` contains `\d`.
- The idea is to match either of the three `([fcl])` after the first dash, then when it comes time for the second dash we match the non-existence of the firstly matched character using negative lookahead followed by any of the three again - `(?!\2)([fcl])`, for the final match we match the non-existence of the firstly or secondly matched character, followed by either of the three - `(?!\2|\4)([fcl])`.
- You can see that this can get complex as the number of possible indicators grows. But the complexity grows linearly, unlike if you just used `|`.
- It wont do any backtracking since the dash is not part of a valid first/last/country name and the back references are only for single characters.

Here is the java escaped version:

```
(\\w+)-([fcl])(\\w+)-(?!\\2)([fcl])(\\w+)-(?!\\2|\\4)([fcl])
```

After running this for `canada-csmith-ljames-f.txt` you will get:

- 1st group = `canada`, 2nd group = `c`
- 3rd group = `smith`, 4th group = `l`
- 5th group = `james`, 6th group = `f`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split your arguments into fields, you can then iterate over these to grab the values:

```
String[] args = filename.split('-');
for (String arg : args)
{
    if (arg.startsWith("f")
    {
        firstName = arg;
    }
    else if (arg.startsWith("c")...
}
```

Using this, your arguments can come in any order in the file name.

Comment: You should be looking at the previous part of the split and exclude the first character. With your solution running this for simple filename like `filip-lcanada-csmith-f.txt` will get you `firstName=f.txt`, `country=csmith`, `lastName=lcanada`.

Comment: Then you will have to do additional parsing, because now you don't know which is which.